# Scrapy requests with double link concatinated with %0D%0A

Tags: url, hyperlink, scrapy, double

Im writing a crawlspider with scrapy and its failing on making requests with correct links it extracts somehow concatenates the base url with the entire link it extracted from the site heres an example i see in the log when it makes requests

http://www.example.com/models%0D%0Ahttp://www.example.com/models/page46/info

I am clueless to why its doing this heres the code if it helps, i need scrapy to use cookies as the site uses authentication

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from Profiles.items import Profiles
#from scrapy.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class MyCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'XSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/welcome/models/46/name/']


    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="pagination"]//a'), callback='make_requests_from_url',follow=True),


    def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36'}
        return Request(url, cookies={'Iremoved cookiesfromThisPost':'ignorethispart'}, headers=headers ,dont_filter=True)


    def start_url2(self, response):
        item = Profiles()
        item['models_per_page'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="modelphoto"]/a//@href').extract()
       return item
```

Comment: Might be that pythons `urlparse.urljoin()` is failing to join these two urls. You should edit your code to provide real urls your using.

Other than that you can you can add a `process_request` argument to your `Rule` which would point to a function which takes a request and returns one, so in it you could fix the broken urls.

Comment: This is actually a bug in scrapy. A few similar issues still open: [#838](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/838), [#1021](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/1021), [#1603](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/1603)